# Error: expression evaluation not supported

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I want to simply increase a column value in database by 1, but I always get `expression evaluation not supported` error/

This is the query I'm using:

```
UPDATE SISTEMSKA_OGRANICENJA SET TRENUTNO = ((SELECT N.TRENUTNO FROM 
SISTEMSKA_OGRANICENJA N WHERE N.KORISNIKID = @KorisnikID AND N.OGRANICENJE = 
@Ogranicenje) + 1) WHERE KORISNIKID = @KOrisnikID 
AND OGRANICENJE = @Ogranicenje
```

I have also tried without declaring N in select statement, but it is still not working.

I also tried

```
UPDATE SISTEMSKA_OGRANICENJA SET TRENUTNO = TRENUTNO + 1) WHERE KORISNIKID 
= @KOrisnikID AND OGRANICENJE = @Ogranicenje
```

I know what the problem is, field `TRENUTNO` is type of `Varchar`. How can I convert it to `int` add 1 and then back to `varchar` all in one query? I know how to do it with two, but it will be slower.

Temporarily, I have done it in 2 queries like this:

```
public static void UvecajTrenutno(Ogranicenja ogranicenje, int korisnikId)
{
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionString))
    {
        int trenutno = -1;
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT TRENUTNO FROM SISTEMSKA_OGRANICENJA WHERE KORISNIKID = @KorisnikID AND OGRANICENJE = @Ogranicenje", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KorisnikID", korisnikId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ogranicenje", ogranicenje);

            FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(dr.Read())
            {
                trenutno = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
            }
        }
        if(trenutno < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doslo je do greske! - Korisnik.Ogranicenje.UvecajTrenutno");
            return;
        }
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("UPDATE SISTEMSKA_OGRANICENJA SET TRENUTNO = @TR WHERE KORISNIKID = @KorisnikID AND OGRANICENJE = @Ogranicenje", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KorisnikID", korisnikId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ogranicenje", ogranicenje);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TR", trenutno + 1);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried casting TRENUTNO into numeric then add 1 then casting it back to varchar?

Comment: No since i do not know how to do it in query. I have done it with 2 queries temporary.

Comment: `@namedoparameters` may or may not be implemented in driver

Comment: Why is this column a varchar in the first place? Can't you change your database design so this column is an integer or bigint? BTW: There is no need for that complex nested select you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your update statement to:

```
UPDATE SISTEMSKA_OGRANICENJA 
    SET TRENUTNO = (cast(TRENUTNO as integer) + 1)
    WHERE KORISNIKID = @KOrisnikID AND OGRANICENJE = @Ogranicenje
```

IIRC correctly (can't check it right now) this should automatically coerce back to varchar, but otherwise change it to

```
UPDATE SISTEMSKA_OGRANICENJA 
    SET TRENUTNO = cast(cast(TRENUTNO as integer) + 1 as varchar(20))
    WHERE KORISNIKID = @KOrisnikID AND OGRANICENJE = @Ogranicenje
```

However as I indicated in the comments, if `TRENUTNO` is supposed to be a numeric value, and if it is intended to be manipulated as such (which seems to be the case as you're doing that now), then it would be better to change this column to be a numeric value (integer, bigint, etc) instead of a string type. This would be the real solution to your problem.

The solution with the casts will fail hard if `TRENUTNO` contains values that cannot be converted to integer.

Small word of warning: I don't have access to a Firebird install right now, I'll verify my answer later today.

Comment: It is supposed to be `varchar` since i store multiple different values inside it and i am aware of that problem. Thanks.

Comment: @AleksaRistic Storing multiple values in a single column is already a design smell, and when you have multiple values in that column, this solution will not work. Consider normalizing your database design: that is create a separate table for these multiple values with a foreign key to this table.

Comment: I am aware of it and i am handling it good. That table has about 100 rows total and besides `TRENUTNO` column it has `TYPE` column which only has values of 1, 2, 3 and where ever type is `1 - TRENUTNO is typeof int; 2 - TRENUTNO is typeof string...`...

Comment: @AleksaRistic No, then `TRENUTNO` will stay null, as null + 1 is null.

Comment: Could i use `coalesce(cast(TRENUTNO as integer), 0)`